How to access/import/mount a zfs file
I've asked my wordpress hosting provider to give me a snapshot of the server as I'm looking to migrate the site elsewhere. What I've been given is a .zfs file.
I was completely unaware of what zfs was before today. I've read some docs and every google search keeps coming back with zfs pools and volumes. I presume I need to mount this file as either a pool or volume but after trying to create zpool and using zpool import -d at the file it still says it can't find any pools.
In short, I'm out of my depth. All I want to do is get some files out of this thing. I can spin up either a temporary Ubuntu or Windows VM to get the job done so any guidance on whichever one is easier to work with and the tools/commands/process I need to browse this thing would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

then tell the provider what exactly you want to use. It was done what you are requested ;)

Fair point. I was expecting a VM image file but will have to be more specific next time.

When you describe it as "WordPress hosting", it's fairly likely that there is no VM dedicated to you – it could be just a ton of HTTP vhosts on the same server, to massively save on resources. (Or it could even be just a single WordPress instance with some multi-tenant mode...)

File names can be misleading, so run file foo.zfs to have it guess the file's contents instead.

If it indeed contains a ZFS filesystem:
Attach it to a virtual disk device using losetup, then use zpool to import that device.

If it contains a zfs send backup stream:
Create a new zpool (inside a blank losetup disk image file to avoid the mess of partitioning) and an empty ZFS dataset/filesystem, then use zfs recv to "restore" the contents.

If it contains some other filesystem, like ext4 (the file name can be misleading):
Attach it using losetup, then mount the loop device as usual. Or just mount the file (the mount command will do the setup).

If it contains a MBR or GPT partition table:
Attach it using losetup -P, then run lsblk -f to see what partitions it has; mount or import them as if it were an HDD.

If it says "gzip compressed data" (a bit of a stretch but I still would not be surprised):
Try again using file -z foo.zfs to see what's inside, then decompress with gunzip.



Ok great I'll try that out now

So I've ran the file command against it as per your first instructuion and it regards it as:
ZFS Snapshot (little-endian-machine), version 17, type: ZFS
It's now attached as /dev/loop4 by using losetup.
fdisk isn't showing loop 4 as a volume. zfs pool import -d  still shows no pools available to import.
Any idea what the next steps are?

That sounds like you're looking at a backup made using zfs send, not at an actual zfs filesystem.

Ok... sounds like a good thing and what I asked the hosting provider to perform. Is there a way to "restore" it on my end or a way to navigate the files within?

Yes, create a fresh empty ZFS pool and filesystem in some place and do a zfs receive into that.

Perfect thank you, I massively appreciate your patience with my noob questions. Just to confirm, you are talking about creating a new pool? Like so - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/setup-zfs-storage-pool#1-overview

Yes, and probably creating a dataset/"filesystem" using 'zfs create' on top of the pool, but I don't remember whether that's necessary for using recv or not. I guess you can try just creating a pool and then recv'ing the backup directly into that.
